# Finding hidden relations between objects with minimum effort

Tags: combinatorics

A room has 100 light bulbs and there is a switch panel outside the room with 100 switches each one controlling one light bulb. The switches are not labelled so it’s not clear which switch controls which bulb.

Assuming that that the status of the light bulbs can only be verified by entering the room (one trip to check the status of all 100 light bulbs), what’s the minimum number of trips into the room needed to label each switch with the corresponding light bulb?

I’ve tried setting half of the set in one state and the other half in the opposite state, such as in a binary system. Then you enter the room and check the status. You then divide the two groups into two further subgroups with opposite states, enter the room again and so forth. This gives 7 total trips. But I am not sure if it’s the minimum.

How do one go about proving the minimum number?
Also, what’s the minimum number of trips for n light bulbs?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I’ve tried setting half of the set in one state and the other half in the opposite state, such as in a binary system. Then you enter the room and check the status. You then divides the two groups in two two further subgroups with opposite states, enter the room again and so forth. This gives 7 total trips. But I am not sure if it’s the minimum. How do you go about proving the minimum number?

Comment: Think in terms of information.  How much information is necessary to specify the links from 100 switches to 100 lights?  How much information do you gather on each entry into the room?

Comment: Right, nice idea. Since there are 100 switches and 100 switches you need to establish 100 links. Every time you enter the room you get 100 ‘bits’ of information. But it’s still not clear to me how to relate the two together?

Comment: Start with a smaller problem, which you can do by hand, e.g., $n = 4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binary strategy works, and is optimal. Suppose you entered the room only six times. For each switch, there is a vector $(s_1,\dots,s_6)$, where for each $i\in\{1,\dots,6\}$, $s_i$ was the state of that switch when you entered the room for the $i^{th}$ time. Since there are $100$ light bulbs and $64$ possible state vectors, there would have to exist two switches with the same state vector. But that means you always did the same thing to those switches, so you cannot distinguish them.

Comment: So based on this argument, would it be correct to say that in general, for n light bulbs: Minimum number of trips  = RoundUP ( log2(n) ) ??

Comment: That is correct.